# How do I get values of an individual row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a program that uses a list and has 2 rows and 5 columns. Every element is an entry. I want to be able to access all the columns of an entire row in the list.

When I access all the elements across all rows at once, it works. But when I try to get the values of a single row it doesn't work

This is the code that works:

```
#Build the grid and append to the listCounter list.
for i in range(2):
    for x in range(5):
        entry = Entry(frame, text="", width=5)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=x)
        listCounter.append(entry)

#Get the value of every row
def btnClick():
    sum = 0
    for puntuation in listCounter:           
        sum += int(puntuation.get())
    print(sum)
```

But when I try to get all entries of a single row using `listCounter[0]`, it doesn't work:

```
def btnClick():
    sum = 0
    for puntuation in listCounter[0]:           
        sum += int(puntuation.get())
    print(sum)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "D:/PyProjects/TestCanvas/Connect4.py", line 25, in btnClick
for puntuation in listCounter[0]:
File "C:\Users\Rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in cget
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

So I've tried to get info about the `listCounter`:

```
print(type(listCounter))   --> <class 'list'>
print(type(listCounter[0]) --> <class 'tkinter.Entry'>
```

What exactly is the problem here and how do I solve it?

Comment: What is the problem with what you tried? What were you expecting to get, and what did you actually get? It's very difficult to help you without more show-and-tell, because, among other things, your terminology has not aligned with mainstream python usage yet. This is normal, but will take extra work on your part to explain properly until it does.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain correctly, i'm kinda confused right now. So what I know is that I loop through the list and I get the values of the 2 rows that I've created. But I just want an exactly row. I just don't know how to get the values of a row without getting the 2 rows. So how could I tell to the function "btnClick" to just get the first row? I've been searching on the internet but I'm not able to find exactly the thing I need.

Comment: I am really having trouble understanding what you want to achieve. Perhaps you can make a minimal example with strings or numbers? Tk doesn't seem to be particularly relevant here. Show your example use-case rather than trying to use prose to describe it.

Comment: I just edited it, hope it is clear now!

Comment: In the first example, if you want to get the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, just use the object `listCounter[0]` as-is. If you absolutely need a copy of that list, do `listCounter[0][:]` or `listCounter[0].copy()` or `list(listCounter[0])`.

Comment: If that is *not* what you are looking for, I think you may need to explain further...

Comment: I just edited it again, I think I focused it in the right way now, if you need any more detail please just tell me! I'm trying my best to to explain the problem that I got and what I want, thank you for your time.

Comment: The first nested loop does not create a 2D list of 2 rows and 5 columns. It creates a single list with 10 entries.

Comment: After that, `btnClick` adds up all ten values, no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a proper 2D list (a list-of-lists), you need to create the nested elements explicitly:

```
for i in range(2):
    row = []
    for x in range(5):
        entry = Entry(frame, text="", width=5)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=x)
        row.append(entry)
    listCounter.append(row)
```

Now you will be able to index `listCounter[0]` and get the elements of the first row. Previously, you had `listCounter` as a single list of 10 elements, and `listCounter[0]` was understandably just an `Entry` object.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution, i've seen what I was missing!
Thank you very much for taking your time to help me!!

Comment: @Barrufet the proper operating procedure is to select the answer that answers your question best by clicking on the check mark next to it. This will give you 2 points, and remove the question from the unanswered queue. Welcome to SO and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

So, looking at this, I think your confusion is of the "type" of listCounter. It is not a list of rows, each of which is a list of items (columns). It's a list of each `Entry`, each of which independently controls the row and column it is in. It's like if you took apart a chessboard's rows and put them all next to each other. You can still go through each row independently, it just takes a little work.

It looks like there's 2 rows and 5 columns, so there's 10 entries total. If you try to print out `len(puntuation)`, I'd guess it's `10`. It also looks like it's stored in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). So, the sum of the first row would be:

```
def btnClick():
    sum = 0
    for puntuation in listCounter[0:5]:
        sum += puntuation.get()
    print(sum)
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yeah it helped me so much to understand what I was missing! Thank you very much really!